# CSS - Make a drop down menu sit behind a background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a js drop down menu and I would like for this to not completely sit on top of everything when it is opened. I have a background image with a transparent middle and I want this to be visible on top of the menu when it comes down.

Attached are two images showing the menu closed and then also the menu opened.

This line places the colours on the left and right edges - background: url("images/background-ls-hr-test.png") no-repeat center scroll;

I wish to have this background sit above the drop down menu. The middle of the image is transparent so you will still be able to see the menu when it is opened. I have tried using z-index with no luck.

Thanks!!

```
html{
font-size: 10px;
font-family: 'opensansr';
max-width: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
background-color: #fff1c0;
}


body{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;    
background: url("images/background-ls-hr-test.png") no-repeat center scroll;
background-position: top;
background-size: 100%;
}
```

[image: Menu Closed]

[image: Menu Opened]

Comment: By *definition* nothing can be behind a background - your request does not make sense.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I am a graphic designer, not a coder. Hard to know everything within a few months.

Comment: Put your 'background' as background to a div which sits above the menu (stacking-wise). If you could put your code in your question we could help more.

Comment: Thank you A Haworth!! That has worked perfectly. Forgive my lack of expertise, this is all new to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the image as it's own div and using z-index has resolved this:

```
.bg-img{
background: url("images/background-ls-hr-test.png") no-repeat center scroll;
background-position: top;
background-size: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}
```